# react js, it does not return the token code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, request

react js, it does not return the token code. In the "postman" it works okay, a method "POST" and in the body I pass in "raw" But when I do it in react js it doesn't return that, what am I doing wrong? Thank you

```
export const apiCallToken = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(apiLogin, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({

    }),
  })


  return aa
```

Answer (score 0):

could you post your React component code? Without it it's hard to understand what's the issue there. The `apiCallToken` function looks fine.

Comment: you can check manually ( in http://america-emer-webcore.dev.emergencias.com.ar/api/login) with postman , POST and in body => "raw" , JSON you send {"username":"Emanuel Lemos, "password": "123213"} and this endpoint its gonna return the token  . There are no issues in back end

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any CORS issues? Maybe enable cors on the backend side. If you don't have access to the backend side and think the backend supports CORS, try a proxy on the frontend.

See [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) link to set up a proxy in react.

Comment: you can check manually ( in http://america-emer-webcore.dev.emergencias.com.ar/api/login) with postman , POST and in body => "raw" , JSON you send {"username":"Emanuel Lemos, "password": "123213"} and this endpoint its gonna return the token  . There are no issues in back end